# How to update one database with dump of another database- MySQL

Tags: mysql

I had made two database with exactly same tables and columns say A and B in mysql. I created dump of database A and then try to update contents of DataBase B using dump of DataBase A. I was using command -->source [path]; ./ What it did that dump of DataBase A completely removed the contents of DataBase B. I was not able figure out how to update one database using dump of another database. Please help me.

Comment: so you have a .sql file backup? just confirming

Comment: If both is exactly the same and you want same data in both why don't you just remove B and create new B from A?

Comment: yes i have 1 .sql file. The thing is that I have one database of older contents and I want to import that data into newer one which already have some contents. Using mysqldump command will delete all data from my newer database I want to avoid that.

Comment: mysqldump file will be created in way that it will delete existing table. if you want to merge the data in databases, you have to write your own sql script.

Comment: thanks a lot but I cannot access columns of tables from name of DataBase. I first has to write USE [database_name] and at that point I lose access of other db. Can you suggest any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through replication. go through these useful links [First link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-same-server-id)

[Second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104700/replicate-tables-from-different-database-of-same-mysql-server)